# How can I add Crow's Feet to UMLet?

Tags: java, entity-relationship

I'm using [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/) for creating class diagrams.

UMLet lets you add custom elements by writing your own Java code for their display. These are then stored as .java files in the programs directory.

How can I add crow's foot relations as custom elements?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the same thing a few years back. I ended up just downloading the source and changing it. I believe I was using Umlet 10.0.3 or 10.3. The file I changed was ***com.umlet.element.base.Relation.java***. Basically it is modifying the property parser code. I added two new endpoints: "m>" and "

In method ***setState*** I added:

```
else if (s.indexOf(">>") >= 0) {
    endArrow = "<<";

// Glenn Crow Foot Mod Begin
} else if (s.indexOf("m>") >= 0) {
    // Mulitplicity set -> crow's foot for ERD
    endArrow = "crowsFoot";
// Glenn Crow Foot Mod End

}
else if (s.indexOf(">") >= 0) {
    if (endArrow.equals("")) endArrow = "<";
}
```

and a bit further down in the same method:

```
else if (s.indexOf("<<") >= 0) {
    beginArrow = "<<";

// Glenn Crow Foot Mod Begin
} else if (s.indexOf("<m") >= 0) {
    // Mulitplicity set -> crow's foot for ERD
    beginArrow = "crowsFoot";
// Glenn Crow Foot Mod End

}
else if (s.indexOf("<") >= 0) {
```

In the ***paintEntity*** method, I added the following:

```
else if (r instanceof Arrow) {
    Arrow arrow = (Arrow) r;

    // Glenn Crow Foot Mod Begin
    if (arrow.getString().equals("crowsFoot")) {
        g2.drawLine( (int) arrow.getX(), (int) arrow.getY() + arrow.getArrowEndA().y,
                     (int) arrow.getX() + arrow.getArrowEndA().x, (int) arrow.getY()    );
        g2.drawLine( (int) arrow.getX(), (int) arrow.getY() + arrow.getArrowEndB().y,
                     (int) arrow.getX() + arrow.getArrowEndB().x, (int) arrow.getY()    );
    // Glenn Crow Foot Mod End

    // A.Mueller Start
    } else if (!arrow.getString().equals("n")
```

I was happy with the result. But I didn't want to put it in each release, and it was never added to the code base (I suspect because it isn't uml-ish enough), so it may be out of date now.

Comment: I just pulled down the 11.5.1 source (latest at this time) and see that the crows foot parts are in there -but unfortunately it is commented out.